# img does not work for htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a code to redirect links like this

```
RewriteEngine On  
Options +FollowSymLinks  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ pages/index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [L]  

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ pages/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

so that

```
localhost/mysite/a
localhost/mysite/a/b
```

go to

```
localhost/mysite/pages/index.php?p=a
localhost/mysite/pages/index.php?p=a&page=b
```

respectively.

I have a code in the index.php with

```
<img src='../pages/images/12345h1.png'>
```

The img works for the link localhost/mysite/a/b but it doesn't work for localhost/mysite/a
is there a way to solve this problem?

for `localhost/mysite/a/b` and `localhost/mysite/a/`
the src becomes `localhost/mysite/pages/images/12345h1.png`
but for `localhost/mysite/a`
the src becomes `localhost/pages/images/12345h1.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your `RewriteCond` only gets applied to next immediate `RewriteRule. Change your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
Options +FollowSymLinks  

# skip rules for files and directories    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ pages/index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ pages/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: for `localhost/mysite/a/b`
the src becomes `localhost/mysite/pages/images/12345h1.png`
but for `localhost/mysite/a`
the src becomes `localhost/pages/images/12345h1.png`

Comment: Your images should have absolute paths rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. OR else you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/mysite/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that I work at my pages on localhost first then I upload them to my website, if I use absolute paths then I have to change them every time I upload the pages to the site.

Comment: I have provided you 2 solutions, you can use 2nd one.